# In >= Windows 8, how might I return all MSMQ Journal entries for named Queue in powershell?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, msmq

As introduced in MSMQ Cmdlets (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh405007(v=vs.85).aspx), we now have the ability to query our queue. If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue
```

Then I get a full list of all queue objects on the system. Good.

If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -QueueType Private
```

Then I get a full list of all Private queue objects on the system. Cool.

However...If I run

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -Name private$\mt_queuename_request_001
```

I don't get anything back...even though I am using a valid name...so, in turn, running

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -Name private$\mt_queuename_request_001 -Journal
```

Also gets me nothing...which I'd really like to be able to get this list of Journal entries.

Advice? Success stories?

Comment: I don't know anything about MSMQ, but in the Get-MsmqQueue examples, we have this: `Get-MsmqQueue -Name Order* -QueueType Private -Journal`. That suggests to me that you could try this: `Get-MsmqQueue -Name mt_queuename_request_001 -QueueType Private -Journal`

Comment: The only real variance here is the addition of the QueueType parameter and that doesn't help any when also providing the name...unless you happened to provide a name for a public but request the private type, of course...which would render absolutely nothing instead of a stand-along useless collection of pixels.

Comment: okay, it was just an idea. I thought maybe it didn't like the `private$` notation. But like I said, I don't know anything about MSMQ. As a rule, it's useful to look at the examples. (`help Get-MsmqQueue -detail`) It might be worth trying wildcards in the name.

Comment: yeah, you can run it without the "private$\" and it actually does return something...just not the list I was hoping for

Answer (score 2):

I see that the post is quite old, but maybe it will help someone, because I was searching for it long time while coming to solution.

To get Queue properties, you can run without specifying Path "private$\"

```
PS C:\Get-MsmqQueue -Name mt_queuename_request_001
```

I'm afraid there is no way of reading messages in Queues using PS Cmdlets.

To read and manipulate messages in MSMQ I am using the following:

```
# Load Messaging Assembly
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | Out-Null

# Get Queue Messages
$queuePath = ("SERVER01\mt_queuename_request_001")
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
$queue.GetAllMessages()

# Get Journal Messages
$queuePath = ("SERVER01\mt_queuename_request_001;JOURNAL")
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath
$queue.GetAllMessages()
```

Regards,
E